# No sé capturar en el cliente el mensaje <message:'Usuario no encontrado' en el siguiente código

Tags: express, react-axios

> cuando son verdaderas las primeras dos condicionales del código del
> backend se recibe todo el contenido
> res.status(200).json({token,userFound,message :'Bienvenido'})
> en el console.log(res) que coloque en el frontend . Pero cuando cualquiera
> de ellas da falsa solo viene del backend null y nunca recibo nada en el
> console.log(res) , solo veo en la consola del navegador lo siguiente:

```
[![mensage que llega a la consola del navegador][1]][1]
```

> Además si existe esta manera de enviar el status y el json() (return
> res.status(400).json({message:'Usuario no encontrado'}),
> y de hecho la recibo cuando se cumplen las condiciones , me gustaría saber
> como hacer para recibir los mensajes del json() cuando se hace falsa alguna de
> las condicionales del backend, gracias por la paciencia

````
**Codigo Backend:**    

    ``` 
        export const signin = async (req,res)=>{    
        try {
        const userFound = await 
        User.findOne({username:req.body.username}).populate("roles")  
        if(!userFound) return res.status(400).json({message:'Usuario no 
        encontrado'})               
        const matchPassword = await 
        User.comparePassword(req.body.password,userFound.password)
        if (!matchPassword) return 
        res.status(401).json({token:null,message:'Contraseña Invalida'})
        const token = jwt.sign({id:userFound._id}, config.SECRET,{
        expiresIn:86400 })          
        res.status(200).json({token,userFound,message :'Bienvenido'})     
         } catch (error) {
             console.log(error)
          } 
      ```
````

**Codigo Frontend:**

````
     const res = await API.post('/auth/signin',payload,)

       try {               
         sessionStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token)                        
         const switComponentsByRoles = res.data.userFound.roles[0].name         
         const userSessionview = res.data.userFound.username 
         const switComponentsByRole = 
              {
                switch:switComponentsByRoles,
                  view:userSessionview
               }       
        localStorage.setItem('usersession', userSessionview) 
        console.log(res)  

       dispatch({        
             type: 'SWITCH_COMPONENTS',
          payload: switComponentsByRole    
         }) 
             authentication()           
       } catch (error) {
         console.log(error)
       }                
} ``` 

 > Agrego que la dirección del backend es: 
    http://localhost:4000/api/auth/signin
 > la del frontend es http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin/ 
 > y que uso una instancia de Axios para las llamadas que también expongo
    ```  import axios from 'axios'

     const BASE_URL= 'http://localhost:4000/api'
     const API = axios.create({    
                   baseURL:BASE_URL,
                   })
     ```      export default API
> Algo curioso: cuando hago al backend la solicitud desde insomnia si captura el 
mensaje y lo muestra


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YRHs.png
````

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar un código similar al siguiente, donde se captura el error (error<> 200):

```
   API.post('/auth/signin',payload).subscribe((resp) => {
      // Código Ok
    }, (err: any) => {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
```

Comment: muchas gracias, por contestar pero no logro aun entender ni recibir el json(), he reformulado la pregunta para ver si puedo explicarme mejor, saludos

Answer (score 0):

El problema no es que no puedas entregar el mensaje, el error está en la solicitud.

La solicitud que realizas esta mal, directamente te tira el error 400 que entrega por defecto el navegador para las malas solicitudes. Si te fijas tu tienes que envié un código de estado 400 con un json y el mensaje, y eso no se esta entregando.

Comprueba la dirección de la solicitud, quizás está mal el puerto o algo pero el problema, según mi punto de vista, no está en el código.

`API.post('/auth/signin',payload)`

Si estás desde el frontend eso tiene otra ruta, como sabe donde está el servidor backend? debes establecer la ruta completa http://localhost:4000/auth/signin.

`API.post('http://localhost:4000/auth/signin',payload)`

Localhost puede ser remplazado por tu dirección en donde tengas el backend al igual que el puerto. Creo que ese es el error.

*Como dato no entiendo a que te refieres con API, deduzco que así llamaste a axios. Como consejo recomiendo llamar a los módulos con el nombre por defecto así sabes que estas tratando, ya si eres un dominador del módulo, no hay problema.*

Comment: Muchas gracias Sr , por ser tan amable en atender mi interrogante, disculpe, es 
       que no agregué en el post, el hecho de  que tengo hecha una instanciación  de 
       axios , aquí la agrego, pero con ella y sin ella  me arroja el mismo                        
       ```import axios from 'axios'
           const BASE_URL= 'http://localhost:4000/api'
           const API = axios.create({    
                   baseURL:BASE_URL                                                                               
           })
          export default APIgo la instancia de axios

Comment: Entiendo, vamos paso a paso, juntos encontraremos el error. Borra lo que te dije lo último de axios. Y pon un ```console.log(res)``` después de la primera línea ```const res = await API.post('/auth/signin',payload,)``` e identifica que muestra en la consola.

Comment: Este es respuesta en la consola del navegador :                                                                                                                  
 POST http://localhost:4000/api/auth/signin 400 (Bad Request)   xhr.js:177
 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400 at createError (createError.js:16)
    
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)     Muchas gracias Sr.

Comment: Tienes algun archivo llamado createError.js? Dice que hay un error en la línea 16. Miralo y dime que dice en esa línea.

Comment: no pude ver nunca la foto que envié en la primera edición de este post , no se que hice mal al adjuntarla , pero quería agregarle que veo en el navegador en el apartado network preview el message ' Usuario no encontrado'

Comment: según observo es un fichero propio de node , llamado module.exports

Comment: Entiendo, la verdad no sabría que decir, ya que, no puedo ver más al respecto. Te queda descubrirlo. Si no es mucho trabajo crea todo desde 0 una y otra vez, es la única manera que podrás descubrir y practicar. Si algo me sirvio a mi cuando hago una API y la consumo desde el frontend es hacerlo una y otra vez. Una vez lo repetí tanto el proceso que ya sé lo que tengo que hacer y como manejar los errores. Otro consejo es manejar los errores con try, catch. Esto ayuda mucho a saber cuando ocurre el error y manejar las excepciones. Lamento no poder ayudarte más.

Comment: Encontré un enlace a un error con codigo similar 16. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604909/axios-createerror-js16-uncaught-in-promise-error-request-failed-with-status  Esta en ingles pero puedes traducirlo con Chrome.

Comment: Gracias Juan Fernando por el tiempo que me has dedicado , se que lleva mucho tiempo esto y a distancia es muy dificil, un fuerte abrazo desde Cuba

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a la comunidad por el tratar de apoyarme, después de unos días tratando de extraer el mensaje que se enviaba desde el backend en esta porción del código : return res.status(400).json({message:'Usuario no encontrado'}), Logre al fin extraerlo y aqui pongo lo que me faltaba agregar:

```
      console.log(error.response)
      
    }
```